# Why does the implicit derivation of this poly function case fails without subtype evidence?

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit, generic-programming, shapeless

There are two similar shapeless polymorphic functions in the following example. The only difference between them is that `deserSucceeding`'s implicit case definition has an additional subtyping evidence `(implicit e: FS <: FromStr[T])`.  Scala fails to derive an implicit `Aux.Case` for `deserFailing`, but succeeds for `deserSucceeding`.

Why? Is this a limitation of the scala compiler or can `deserSucceeding` lead to an ambiguity in the implicit derivation / type inference?

```scala
import shapeless._
type FromStr[T] = String => T
object FromDouble extends FromStr[Double] {
  override def apply(v1: String): Double = v1.toDouble
}

object deserFailing extends Poly2 {
  implicit def kase[T, FS <: FromStr[T]]: Case.Aux[String, FS, T] = at((s, fs) => fs(s))
}
// fails to derive a `Case.Aux`
deserFailing("1.0", FromDouble)

object deserSucceeding extends Poly2 {
  implicit def kase[T, FS](implicit e: FS <:< FromStr[T]): Case.Aux[String, FS, T] = at((s, fs) => fs(s))

}
deserSucceeding("1.0", FromDouble)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TL;DR; is how type inference works.

When you do `[T, FS <: FromStr[T]]` the compiler tries to infer both at the same type and as such it probably end up inferring **Any** or **Nothing** from one of those to make the subtype constraint to type-check.
Whereas the second option doesn't force any subtype restriction during inference which makes the compiler to infer better types and then after that it will check the subtyping constraint.

It is similar to this example:

```scala
def tupleIfSubtype1[T <: U, U](t: T, u: U) = (t, u)
def tupleIfSubtype2[T, U](t: T, u: U)(implicit ev: T <:< U) = (t, u)

tupleIfSubtype1("Foo", 3) // compiles, it infers Any for the second element.
tupleIfSubtype2("Foo", 3) // doesn't compile.
```

More in-depth explanation, [here](https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html).